# Reading from txt file into a FIFO queue for processing

Tags: c++, sorting, queue, text-files, heapsort

Im confused on how to use queues and how to implement them. I would have to read the packets sequentially, then into queues for processing. Once that is done, I would have to read packets sequentially from queues and redirect them into one of two priority queues based on their VLAN tag and priority number, this is an example of what is in the text file, but there is about 10000 of them.

55555555555555D507E34B68534300A0FF7538958100010000086461746162617365C704DD7B
[This is what the numbers mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGTGV.png)

The problem I am having is with queues themselves, I feel that Im going the wrong way with all this, I would appreciate some help.

https://pastebin.com/B4ZG2RmL <- this is the header

```
using namespace std;

struct packetItem
{
    string packet;
    int packetInt;
};

int main()
{
    packetItem newItem;
    ifstream myfile("packets.txt");
    int count = 0;
    int vlan = 0, priority = 0;
    const int v = 100;
    char sArray[v];



    const int size = 100;

    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        //while (myfile.good()) 
        while (count < 10) // this 10 is here so it doesnt spam the output
        {
            myfile >> newItem.packet;
            myfile.get(); //remove return
            strcpy_s(sArray, newItem.packet.c_str());
            int x = 0;

            while (sArray[x] != '\0')
            {
                x++;
                string part(sArray.substr(48, 4));
            }
            cout << count + 1 << ". " << sArray << "\n\t" <<x << "\n";
            count++;
        }   
    }
    myfile.close();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the specific problem? BTW do you need to copy the string into the char array? Why not just leave it in the string?

Comment: `sArray.substr(48, 4)` makes no sense - `sArray` is not of a class type. Anyway, the question is supposedly about queues, but your code doesn't mention any. It's not clear what it is you are asking, exactly.

Comment: To answer your question, don't implement a queue, use [`std::queue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue).  Otherwise implement using linked list or array, your choice.

Answer (score 2):

C++ comes with a standard implementation of a queue data structure. [Take a look](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue)!

Here is a quick example using your packets:

```
std::queue<packetItem> pack_queue();
packetItem item;

while (/* What ever condition you choose */) {
        stream >> item.packet;
        pack_queue.push(item);

        /* Process packet */       
}

/* When you want to get the top packet, then just do this */
packetItem front_packet = pack_queue.front();
```

I know this is a very brief example, so take a look at the documentation to get a better grasp.

I hope this answers your questions. It is kind of broad.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I see many issues that we can address in your code. Some are important and some just nice to have. But let's star:

1. You said you wish you will have "queues". In that case, I would say, use std:queue (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/queue/), this will give you a chance to save a lot of time and will make your code cleaner.
2. You said, that you wish you will have many prioritized queues. I would say that's nothing more than std::vector of std::queues, so will end up with something like this:

`std::vector<std::queue<Frame>> queues;`

3. Then you can pack it in a little bit of structure:

//

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <experimental/optional>

template <class T> class Scheduler {
     private:   std::vector<std::queue<T>> queues;

     public:
        Scheduler(int maxSize) {
            queues = std::vector<std::queue<T>>(maxSize);
        };

        void schedule(int priority, const T& object) {
            std::cout << "enqueue on queue #" << priority << std::endl;
            queues[priority].push(object);
        };
        std::experimental::optional<T> take(int priority) {
            std::experimental::optional<T> result;
            if (!queues[priority].empty()) {
                result = std::experimental::optional<T>(queues[priority].front());
                queues[priority].pop();
            }
            return result;

        };
};
```

4. So the usage is much clear then:

   ```
    Scheduler<int> scheduler(5);

    scheduler.schedule(0, 10);
    scheduler.schedule(0, 14);

    for (std::experimental::optional<int> o = scheduler.take(0); (bool)(o) == true; o = scheduler.take(0)) {
        std::cout << "O " << o.value() << std::endl;
    }
   ```
5. That's all about queues... but now you need to prepare a structure/class describing your data. Something like:

   class Frame {
       std::string preamble;
       std::string mac;
       int vlanId;
       /// ... and so one
   }

Then you have to split your message into small parts, but not using char* (which comes from c language) but using std::string.substr(n,p);

So let say you will have something like this in your code:

```
myfile >> line;
Frame frame;
frame.preamble = line.substr(0, LEN_OF_PREAMBLE);
frame.mac = line.substr(LEN_OF_PREAMBLE, LEN_OF_MAC);
//... and so one
scheduler.push(frame.vlan, frame);
```